# Есть ли у ImageMagic возможность при одной команде convert сделать несколько файлов?

Tags: изображения, imagemagick, resize

Смысл в следующем: есть большущий файл, который нужно масштабировать в 10-15 разных размеров. Делать простой batch через API или .sh файл очень не резонно, так как очень много уходит времени именно на загрузку исходного файла, а не на его ресайз.

```
convert -profile Profiles/CMYK/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc t.psd'[0]' -profile Profiles/RGB/AdobeRGB1998.icc -resize 600x600  out-600.png
```

Хочу поинтересоваться, может кто знает, есть ли возможность у ImageMagic при одном вызове команды convert сразу сгенерировать несколько размеров в разные файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашелся:

```
convert -profile Profiles/CMYK/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc t.psd'[0]'                             \
 -respect-parentheses                                                                     \
\( -clone 0 -profile Profiles/RGB/AdobeRGB1998.icc -resize 600x600 +write out-600.png \)  \
\( -clone 0 -profile Profiles/RGB/AdobeRGB1998.icc -resize 400x400 +write out-400.png \)  \
\( -clone 0 -profile Profiles/RGB/AdobeRGB1998.icc -resize 200x200 +write out-200.png \)  \
null:
```